# How to get push notification status using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In my app there is a setting to enable/disable push notification. Everything is fine with registering and my app is getting the notification.

Now I also unregister using `UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()` when I change in setting.

But when I try to fetch the status that app is already registered or not using `UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` then it always returns me `true`.

Any solution, how can I solve this?

Comment: In which iOS version are you checking this functionality and are you checking in Simulator or in real device?

Comment: I believe that that method will always return `true` if the app has ever successfully completed remote notification registration. If the user doesn't want notifications then they can either disable them in the settings for your app, or you can update your back end database to either flag that notifications should not be sent or remove the push registration token.

Comment: Hi @DarshanPatel I'm using iOS 12.2 and testing in the real device.

Comment: Hey, @Paulw11 Thanks for your suggestion. There is no any other solution without using server call?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented in this way in my app for push notification settings.

- When user opt-out for push notification then I called an **api(updateNotificaitonStatus with parameter "isEnabled = false")** that disable the flag at server side for the push notification.
- So whenever server has some data to send then...the server will check that is push notification enabled for the user?, if not, then just ignore to send the notification.
- And if user changes his mind, and enabled the notification from app then agin an api call with the true flag(**updateNotificaitonStatus with parameter "isEnabled = true"**).